# What is 'long?' data type?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am going over some code written by another developer and am not sure what `long?` means:

```
protected string AccountToLogin(long? id)
{
   string loginName = "";
   if (id.HasValue)
   {
      try
      {....
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`long` is the same as `Int64`

[long data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

The `?` means it is nullable

> A nullable type can represent the
>   normal range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an
>   additional null value

[Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Nullable example:

```
int? num = null;
if (num.HasValue == true)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
}
```

This allows you to actually check for a `null` value instead of trying to assign an arbitrary value to something to check to see if something failed.

I actually wrote a blog post about this [here](http://robertgreiner.com/2010/04/write-better-code-using-nullable-with-csharp/).

Comment: Links in answer are outdated.

Comment: Blog post is 404.

Answer (score 15):

`long` is an [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx), the `?` makes it [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

long? is a 64-bit, nullable integer.

To clarify, nullable means it can be null or an integer number ( 0, 1, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

"long?" is a nullable 64-bit signed integer. It's equivalent to `Nullable<Int64>`.

Answer (score 4):

`long?` is a nullable type. This means that the `id` parameter can have a long value or be set to `null`. Have a look at the `HasValue` and `Value` properties of this parameter.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [nullable type declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx).